# Python Method/Function

Tags: python, function, numpy, methods

hi I just started teaching myself Python couple of days ago and right now got really confused about the usage of"." when calling Method/Function. when def is created within a class, it would be a"Method", where you would have to call it by typing "the name of the instance "."the name of the method"() 
this makes sense because the first argument "self" is connected to the instance created.

however, when using Numpy I encountered a "function" np.random.rand() 
How is this possible? this function already has two objectives(np,random). how can this be created when using only two elements "package(class)" and "moduel(def)". what does "." mean in this function? Thank you

Comment: In the end it's all really objects and functions; the differentiation between "module", "class", "object" and "method" serves mostly to clarify usage.

Comment: What do you mean "two objectives"? What do you mean "moduel(def)"?

Comment: Sorry i meant object. what i meant by module(def) is the def(within the class)=module(within the package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, just like in Java, it is possible to define classes. Classes are representations of a concept that you want to include in your code. For example, imagine that you create a `person` class where you want to store name and height. A very simple implementation could be:

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name, height):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height

    def grow_up(self, cm):
        self.height += cm
        return
```

In this case, `__init__(self, name, height)` and `grow_up(self, cm)` are methods: they are defined inside a class and they take as a first argument `self`, that is, the instance of the class itself. An instance of the class is, in this example, any single person that you associate with this class. For example

```
a = person("John", 120)
```

Now, `a` is an instance of the class person and the arguments `"John"` and `120` are passed to the special initializer method  `__init__`. If you call `a.height` you will obtain 120. (Should you use a getter for that? Maybe yes, maybe no, but that's not the point of your question)

Using the method `grow_up` is as simple as typing

```
a.grow_up(10)
```

Calling `a.height` again you now obtain 130.

A function is not defined inside a class, therefore, it can't have a `self` variable. It is similarly defined with a `def` command, however, which can generate some confusion. To make things even more ambiguous for beginners, python defines modules and packages. A module is a collection of functions stored in a single file, and a package is a directory containing one or more such modules. The standard way of navigating the namespace is the same as for class functions: using a dot (`.`) to separate packages, modules, and functions, going from the outermost to the innermost level.

Comment: thanks for your clear response. so to conclude it, the dot notation in "a.grow_up(int)"or"a.height" is different from the dot notation used when calling a function contained in one of many modules in a certain package? such as "np.random.rand()"or"time.time()"

Comment: No, but yes. No, because they both serve to navigate a namespace (height is defined just inside instances of the class Person, just like the random function is defined in the np.random package). But yes, because the namespaces are defined by different structures, classes on one side and packages / modules on the other.

The utility of having such a namespace navigator is to allow different functions and/or methods with the same name to exist in different namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

The `rand()` function you want to use is part of the `random` module of the `numpy` package.
Without going deep into packages and namespace structure, here is a quick example of why this matters:

If you import packages, you load additional functions, classes and structures into your namespace. But maybe you want to use `math` and `numpy`, which both have a `sin()`-function:

```
import numpy as np
import math
a = np.sin()
b = math.sin()
```

`a` and `b` are not the same function, but have the same name, so it is useful to call them by the name of the containing package.

The same applies for the standard `sum()` and the `np.sum()`.

If you explicitly want to use the `rand()` function without calling it by the full name, you can do that by
from numpy.random import rand

Answer (score 0):

Package `np`, package `random` and function `rand` effectively are python objects. Objects can have attributes and you can access them with dot notation and this chain (`obj.attr1.attr2...attrN`) can be long.

So in your example you just access attribute `rand` of attribute `random` of package `np`, and since `rand` is a callable object, you call it with `rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using numpy or any other packages it will not create a object.
For example:

```
import numpy as np
```

It will only download this package and you can use it.
In other words you can say numpy is a folder and it contain subfolders and scripts. Random is a subfolder. Rand() is a function.

Conclusion:

```
np.random.rand()
```

You are using dots to define a path for this function.

Here is a code for numpy package: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy